# how to manipulate an image in python to mimic macular degenerative

Tags: python, image-processing

Im trying to find a good package or algorithm to modify an image to push the center of an image outwards to mimic macular degen. The best method I found was image_slicer package and split image into 4 pieces, push the inner corners and stitch images back. But, the join method of the package is not working and documentation is unclear. Does anyone have a package that can do this?

Also, I am trying to push the outside of an image in, to create tunnel vision.

(for both of these I am still trying to preserve the image, although skewed is fine, I am trying to prevent image loss.)

some code I wrote

```
import image_slicer
#split image into 4 pieces
image_slicer.slice('piegraph.jpeg',4) #just a simple sample img

#code to resize corners
#I can figure this out later.

#stitch images back
tiles = ("pie_01_01.png","pie_01_02.png","pie_02_01.png","pie_02_02.png")
image_slicer.join(tiles)
```

Comment: ultimately what I want to do is push the center pixels of the image out so simulate a black hole and the image surrounding are the pixels bunched together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use opencv and numpy to do what you want.

If I understand correctly what you need is a mapping that take the original image and maps them as a function of the distance from the center of the image.

For all the pixels inside the "black hole" you want to be black and all others you want them to be bunched together.

So if we take the original image to be:

[image: Before]

The result you are looking for is something like:

[image: After]

The following code dose this. The parameters that you need to play with are

RBlackHole - The radius of your black hole

FACTOR - Changes the amount of "bunching" too small and all the pixels will mapped also to black too large and they will not be bunched.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# Read img
img = cv2.imread('earth.jpg')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape

# Params
FACTOR = 75
RBlackHole = 10

# Create a 2d mapping between the image and a new warp
smallSize = min(rows,cols)
xMap = np.zeros((rows,cols), np.float32)
yMap = np.zeros_like(xMap)
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):

        # Calculate the distance of the current pixel from the cneter of the image
        r = math.sqrt((i-rows/2)*(i-rows/2) + (j-cols/2)*(j-cols/2))

        # If the pixles are in the radius of the black hole
        # mapped them to a location outside of the image.
        if r <= RBlackHole:
            xMap[i, j] = rows*cols
            yMap[i, j] = rows*cols
        else:

            # Mapped the pixels as a function of the distance from the center.
            # The further thay are the "buncher thay will be"
            xMap[i, j] = (r-RBlackHole)*(j - cols/2)/FACTOR + cols/2
            yMap[i, j] = (r-RBlackHole)*(i - rows/2)/FACTOR + rows/2



# Applay the remmaping
dstImg = cv2.remap(img,xMap,yMap,cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Save output image
cv2.imwrite("blackHoleWorld.jpg", dstImg)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good example. I can work with this. Good job.